# Why should I use Bloc with a Calendar instead of a Static Map?

Tags: flutter, bloc

In Flutter, I want to use a calendar from the [table_calendar package](https://pub.dev/packages/table_calendar) in order to set shifts and assign employees to them.

Also to do so I am using a local database from the [sqflite package](https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite).

I have seen a few tutorials online, e.g., [Database Storage in Flutter using Sqflite](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E4yRzqChFxY), that combine the database with Bloc technology.

For my calendar, I need a `Map<DateTime,List<dynamic>>` to control the events. As of now, I used a static map that I would use in different classes, e.g., shift_form and shift_calendar.

The Bloc implementation would start somehow like this:

`class ShiftBloc extends Bloc<ShiftEvent, Map<DateTime,List<dynamic>> {...`

Why should I use Bloc instead of a static Map?

Also is it even possible to use a Bloc as a Map data structure? **Edit: -> Yes it 
is**

But how should I implement Blocs for the Streams that I am getting from Firestore as a Map instead of a List?

P.S. I am using the [Flutter Firestore Todos Tutorial](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/flutterfirestoretodostutorial) structure.

Answer (score 6):

As a general rule, you never "have" to use BLoC for anything.

BLoC and other State Management strategies are meant to make it easier to deal with data that multiple parts of your App need at the same time, and need to be updated when that data changes.

For simple Widgets, low dependency on data, a simple `setState` should be more than enough and there's nothing wrong using it.

Some people just use State Management with everything without stopping to analyze the problem at hand, this makes the code more confusing for not reason.

If your `Map` is local, just use it locally, if you need it in several places, than avoid using it as a global variable as this makes testing a lot harder.

Remember, a BLoC is just a class with Streams as ouputs and Syncs as inputs, the Firebase Firestore class already provides you with a Stream, so your BLoC could be just a Stream transformation adapting the data on Firestore to your Map. I can't really say how to make this as I am not aware with your data.

Comment: This is great. Yes, the HashMap is going to get used in multiple classes, thus I had to make it static.

Comment: On another note, I created a small project to tackle this problem and is up in Github https://github.com/georgiossalon/schedulingapp. For the HashMap example, choose the **bloc_with_map** branch. I am having a small problem though. The code does not recognize state changes on the fly when I manually change a shift's (document) property. The UI gets only updated after I restart the app. I found that the problem lies at this line `  List<Object> get props => [shiftsMap];` within the class **shifts_state.dart**. Any suggestions?

Comment: Also, the structure in the test project is taken from the following tutorial: https://bloclibrary.dev/#/flutterfirestoretodostutorial

Comment: I can't take a look at it right now, but try to avoid global variables, use Provider instead, otherwise your tests could be harder to implement.